# How to collect multiple files in array after upload using Angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need one help.I have multiple file upload functionality in my app.Here i need to collect all files in an array so that i can upload those and also display them after selecting.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Image{{$index+1}}:</span>
 <div>
<div ng-class="{'myError': billdata.uploadme_{{$index}}.$touched && billdata.uploadme_{{$index}}.$invalid }">
<input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload_{{$index}}" id="bannerimage_{{$index}}"  ng-model="mul.image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-min-height="400" ngf-resize="{width: 400, height:400}"  ngf-select="onFileSelect('upload_{{$index}}',mul.image);">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<span class="input-group-btn" ng-show="showImage{{$index}}">
<img ng-src="{{attachmultipleimage_$index}}" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" ng-click="addNewImageRow(mulImage);" ng-show="$last"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"  ng-show="mulImage.length>1" ng-click="deleteNewImageRow(mulImage,$index);">
 </span>
 <div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.uploadme_{{$index}}.$error" ng-if="billdata.uploadme_{{$index}}.$touched">
 <p ng-message="maxSize" style="color:#F00;">File is too large.Max size is 2 mb.</p>
 <p ng-message="minHeight" style="color:#F00;">Minimum height should be 400px</p>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Here when i am clicking on `plus` button one new image row is creating and similarly when i will click on `minus` button one image uploading row will eliminate.My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.mulImage=[];
   $scope.mulImage.push({'image':null});
   $scope.addNewImageRow=function(mulImage){
       mulImage.push({'image':null});
   }
   $scope.deleteNewImageRow=function(mulImage,index){
       mulImage.splice(index,1);
   }
   $scope.onFileSelect = function(name,$files,index) {
        var files =$files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
             var file = files[i];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded(index); 
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
   }
```

I have already done something.Here i need to display the selected image (`img ng-src="{{attachmultipleimage_$index}}"`) in each new created row and collect all the selected files to upload.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) is better suited for you because it has this functionality built in. It's [file uploader instance](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API#fileuploader) has an array `queue` which contains all the selected files and also has lots of helper methods.

[this example](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/image-preview/) does what you want to do, select multiple image files and preview them.

Major code would be:

```js
angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload'])
  .controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader',
      function($scope, FileUploader) {
        // create an instance
        $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
          url: 'upload.php'
        });
      });
```

Then you can use it like:

```html
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple />
<br/>
<div ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
  <strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong>
  <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" ng-thumb="{ file: item._file, height: 100 }"></div>
</div>
```

[`ng-thumb`](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/examples/image-preview/directives.js) is a directive written by it's author for image preview example.

In short, just grab this [image-preview](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/tree/master/examples/image-preview) and modify it if necessary

Comment: I have already used `ng-file-upload`.Can you make my code workable?

Comment: @satya well then ignore this answer. I thought I'll share the easiest way to achieve what you're asking. Maybe it'll help others. But I'll take a look if you can create a working demo of your code.

Comment: Ok,I will follow your answer.Actually in my whole project i have used `ng-file-upload` thats why i was telling you.

Answer (score 0):

The following will allow to add files to the queue and remove them. The key is to use `ngf-keep="true"`.

```
<button ngf-select ng-model="allFiles" ngf-keep="true">Add File</button>

<div ng-repeat="f in allFiles">
    <img ngf-thumbnail="f">
    <button ng-click="removeFile($index)">delete</button>
</div>

<button ng-click="upload()">upload all</button>


$scope.removeFile = function(index) {
    $scope.allFiles.splice($index, 1);
    $scope.allFiles = $scope.allFiles.slice(0);
}

$scope.upload = function() {
    Upload.upload({..., data: {file: allFiles}});
}
```

Comment: your ng-click to remove the images in the array is popping up with an error saying `Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined` . I had before where the button was: `ng-click="f = null"` but that was having some un wanted side effects. Any solutions to work around your answer?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle? allFiles cannot be undefined since you are calling remove from the ng-repeat.